# Is python dict very slow for searching key?

Tags: python, dictionary

In the code below, rel_column is a string, and 'id_map' is a python dict and it has 2.2 million key-value pair.

```
if rel_column in id_map:
   node_ids = id_map[rel_column]
```

In debugging a speed bottleneck issue, my colleague said that this piece of code is the cause of the slowness. He said that the 'if' statement takes log(n) time, but my impression has been that for searching a key in a map or set, the complexity has been constant time O(1). Considering that the the total size is only 2.2 millions of the dict, this should not be the speed bottleneck.

I am confused. Is my colleague right?

Comment: You are approximately correct, is O(1) expected time, you could have objects with many hash key collisions that could deteriorate the performance of the lookup

Comment: The colleague is my boss :)

Comment: You can point your boss to this page: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Your colleague is incorrect. Checking if a key is in a dictionary is constant time. It is *designed for this very opertation*, it's a hashmap

Comment: Now, hashmaps can degrade to O(N) time for this if there are many, many hash collisions. In any case, your colleague is probably assuming `dict` is implemented using a binary tree, perhaps they have a C++ background?

Comment: Also, unless Python has some way to optimise this (?), your code is potentially inefficient because you're asking Python to check if the key exists and then, if it does, go fetch its value - which, presumably, means searching for the key again. Use *id_map.get(res_column, None)* providing None would not be an expected value

Comment: @marlon its about time to replace a boss.. :-) Use `timeit` and show him a demo.

Comment: @BrutusForcus, what's the normal way of checking if a key exists in a dict?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga for a 2-million size, there typically won't be many collisions?

Comment: @BrutusForcus that is almost certainly not a bottleneck. Hashmap lookups are everywhere in Python. Heck, every time you look up a global variable it is a hash-based lookup, or every time you do an attribute lookup on a non-slotted, user-defined class.

Comment: Just rename the variable to `id_unordered_map`, then they'll probably think it's O(1).

Comment: @marlon that entirely depends on the nature of your data, not it's size, but Python dicts are highly optimized. Probably, you arent' encountering this situation.

Comment: But why are you iterating over the keys and asking for them? Why not simply iterate at the same time over key, value pairs using [items](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)?

Comment: @balderman I will add timeit statement.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Does that matter for speed here? OK. If found, it will save one get() operation.

Comment: @marlon AFAIK it does

Comment: @DaniMesejo they aren't iterating at all?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True, I misread the question

Comment: @DaniMesejo an extra `get` operation won't save any significant amount of time

Comment: "the normal way of checking if a key exists in a dict?" — `if key in dictionary:` or using `get()` method as @BrutusForcus suggested.

Comment: @martineau that's what I am using in the code.

Comment: Ask him, why he thinks it is O(n) time - and then ask him what the look-up time is for a hash-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python will find keys in O(1) on average.  But complexity is not the only factor in execution time.  For example accessing a list item by its index is also O(1) but it is considerably faster than accessing a dictionary by its key.

I tried replacing your code with:

```
node_ids = id_map.get(rel_column,node_ids)
```

thinking that it could accelerate the process by making only one dictionary access but it didn't improve performance at all (it was actually slower).

In order to prove that dictionary key access isn't O(logN), I benchmarked accessing existing and missing keys from dictionaries of various sizes.  If a binary search was used internally, performance would decrease with size and missing keys would be the worst case scenario thus requiring more time than existing keys (which they don't):

```
id_map1 = {str(i):str(i+1) for i in range(2_000_000)} # LogN = 20
id_map2 = {str(i):str(i+1) for i in range(100_000)}   # LogN = 16
id_map3 = {str(i):str(i+1) for i in range(5_000)}     # LogN = 12

highHits = ["-1","0","1000","2000","2"]*10000     # 50,000
lowHits  = ["-1","0","-1000","-2000","-2"]*10000  # 50,000

from timeit import timeit

print("2M/high  ",timeit(lambda: [id_map1[k] if k in id_map1 else None for k in highHits],number=1))
print("100K/high",timeit(lambda: [id_map2[k] if k in id_map2 else None for k in highHits],number=1))
print("5K/high  ",timeit(lambda: [id_map3[k] if k in id_map3 else None for k in highHits],number=1))

print("2M/low   ",timeit(lambda: [id_map1[k] if k in id_map1 else None for k in lowHits],number=1))
print("100K/low ",timeit(lambda: [id_map2[k] if k in id_map2 else None for k in lowHits],number=1))
print("5K/low   ",timeit(lambda: [id_map3[k] if k in id_map3 else None for k in lowHits],number=1))
```

Results:

```
# existing keys
2M/high   0.003838191999999907
100K/high 0.004719815000000072
5K/high   0.0046313949999996495

# Missing keys
2M/low    0.003382090999999754
100K/low  0.003280908000000249
5K/low    0.0034408550000000204
```

So, the performance doesn't decrease with the size of the dictionary (if anything it improves). And missing keys are identified faster than existing keys which precludes a binary search.  So Python dictionaries do not have O(logN) complexity for key accesses.

Comment: Key search in dict is O(1) on average. Why do you say it's O(logN)?

Comment: So the benchmark shows that existing keys and missing keys don't differ much?

Comment: I'm not saying that it's O(logN). Actually i'm saying the opposite in an attempt to refute what you mentioned you "coleague/boss" was saying.

Comment: Missing keys are identified 15 to 20% faster than existing keys.  I'm guessing that Python is using a hashing bucket algorithm that allows it to know early that the candidate bucket does not contain the key without having to dig into it. (that's just a guess though, I don't know that for sure)

Comment: So each search takes about 0.003-0.004 mill-seconds in your testing. Right?

Comment: No, 0.003-0.004 seconds is the time to loop and perform 50,000 searches.  That is equivalent to 0.06-0.08 microseconds (or 60-80 nanoseconds) per loop + key look up. I'm using a 2.9 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i9 laptop.

Comment: How is this compared to Peter's benchmark? That is one million search takes 0.11 seconds.

Comment: It is very similar, 110 nano seconds compared to 60-80 can be explained by the difference in hardware and Python implementation on the OS platform.

Comment: Or maybe the string length is 8, longer than yours.

Answer (score 6):

When it doubt, benchmark.  Arbitrarily choosing random strings of length 8 for key and value, and using the size specified in the question.

```
import random
import string
import timeit

def randstr(N):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(N))

id_map = {randstr(8): randstr(8) for _ in range(int(2e6))}

# key not present
x = randstr(8)
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=lambda: id_map[x] if x in id_map else None, number=1000000))

# key present, first with in/[], then with .get()
x = random.choice(list(id_map.keys()))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=lambda: id_map[x] if x in id_map else None, number=1000000))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=lambda: id_map.get(x, None), number=1000000))
```

Results:

```
0.11468726862221956
0.13692271895706654
0.13748164474964142
```

Conclusions (Python 3.9, well-distributed keys, small data, 2M entries):

- key not found is slightly faster than key found
- `in` followed by `[]` is about the same speed as `.get()`
- Both are on the order of 100ns per lookup